# ElasticSearch-Kibana Connection Error: Unable to Connect

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I have an elasticsearch server with host h1 running at port 9200. And i have a separate kibana server with host h2 running on port 5601. I have configured both of them properly and then tried to see the GUI of kibana.
It says Status:Red and in the error i see "Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at h1:9200"

I ran the basic troubleshoot mentioned in the elk documentation i.e. to check whether kibana.yml's elasticsearch.url field is properly referring to h1:9200 or not and vice versa for elasticsearch.yml's fields. Everything seems to be fine. What could be any other reason for this error? How to fix the same?

Answer (score 1):

Could be for a number of reasons, connectivity/network configuration usually the prime suspect - check out [this](http://logz.io/blog/troubleshooting-5-common-elk-glitches/) troubleshooting article for possible solutions